# How to set volume for chromeless youtube API?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have used chromeless youtube API for playing youtube videos through youtube ID and I have used to set volume

```
player.setVolume = 50;
```

and

```
player.getVolume();
```

but its not updating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the API [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html), it is `player.setVolume(50)`, not `player.setVolume = 50`.

Member names with "set", like `setSomething`, are usually methods, not properties. If the volume was meant to be set using assignment, it would probably be just player.volume = 50, without "set".

Comment: I thought... it was like a setter function. Thanks.